# Segmentation fault in qt while trying to return data from linked list

Tags: c++, qt, linked-list, segmentation-fault

im programming with qt and ive came across a segmentation fault that i dont know how to solve. The purpose of the program is to add a contact to a linked list via an interface when i press a button, it can also sort the contact by their first name or last name. Im pretty sure the issue comes from my object "List" in the class linkedlist (i declare it in mainwindow.h , public). "List" is a list of all the contact. I can add a contact in the list via lLContactAdd which is done in void MainWindow::on_pbAjouter_clicked(). However, the object "list" doesn't seems  exist for the other fonction like void MainWindow::on_rbPreN_clicked(). When i go in the function on_rbPreN_clicked() and use a "get()" to retrieve a contact from the list, it gives me a segmentation fault in debug but it doesn't give me one in LLContactAdd(), probably because theres nothing to return in the Node or the list doesn't exist for the whole program.
Also, LLContactAdd() will always add the same contact over and over (the last one i entered).
Here's the program, sorry if its pretty big. feel free to ask me about part of the code if you dont understand it. Ive left a few comments in the mainwindow.cpp. I hope you guys can help me! *sorry for the mediocre english, im a french student. **PLEASE let me know if you dont understand some part of my explanation ill be ready to give more info.**

```
#ifndef CONTACT_H
#define CONTACT_H
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>

class Contact
{

    QString _prenom;
    QString _nom;
    QString _tel;
    QString _email;
public:
    Contact();

    Contact(QString prenom,QString nom, QString tel, QString email);

    QString prenom();
    void setPrenom(QString prenom);
    QString nom();
    void setNom(QString nom);
    QString tel();
    void setTel(QString tel);
    QString email();
    void setEmail(QString email);
};

#endif // CONTACT_H

#ifndef LISTECONTACT_H
#define LISTECONTACT_H
#include <contact.h>
#include "node.h"
#include <QString>

class ListeContact
{

    Node *head = 0;
    int _size;
    Contact _c;

public:

    ListeContact();
    void lLContactAdd(Contact c);
   // ~ListeContact();
    Contact & get(int index);
    void remove(int index);
    int getSize();


};


#endif // LISTECONTACT_H

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include "listecontact.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

     ListeContact liste; // this is where i create a global object which is my list(im not sure this works)

private slots:
    void on_pbAjouter_clicked();

    void on_rbNomP_clicked();

    void on_rbPreN_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include "contact.h"

class Node
{
public:
    Contact &_c;
    Node(Contact &c);
    Node * _next;



};

#endif // NODE_H
```

now cpp

```
#include "Contact.h"
#include<QString>
#include "listecontact.h"
Contact::Contact()
{

}
Contact::Contact(QString prenom, QString nom, QString tel, QString email) :

 _prenom(prenom),_nom(nom),_tel(tel), _email(email)
 {}
QString Contact::prenom(){
    return _prenom;
}
void Contact::setPrenom(QString prenom){
    _prenom= prenom;
}
QString Contact::nom(){
    return _nom;
}
void Contact::setNom(QString nom){
    _nom= nom;
}
QString Contact::tel(){
    return _tel;
}

void Contact::setTel(QString tel){
    _tel=tel;
}
QString Contact::email(){
    return _email;
}

void Contact::setEmail(QString email){
    _email = email;
}

#include "listecontact.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "contact.h"

ListeContact::ListeContact():head(0),_size(0)
{

}
void ListeContact::lLContactAdd(Contact c)
{
    Node * tmp = new Node(c);

    if(head)
    {
        Node * current = head;
        while(current->_next) current = current->_next;
        current->_next=tmp;

    }
    else  head = tmp;
    _size++;
    qDebug()<<_size;
}
int ListeContact::getSize()
{
    return _size;
}


/*ListeContact::~ListeContact()
{
    Node * current = head;
    while(current)
    {
        Node* tmp = current;
        current = current->_next;

        delete tmp;
    }
}*/
Contact & ListeContact::get(int index)
{
    Node * current = head;
    while(index>0 && current->_next)
    {
        current = current->_next;
        index--;
    }
    return current->_c; // this is where the debug put the segmentation fault but only when i call the funtion void MainWindow::on_rbPreN_clicked() or void MainWindow::on_rbNomP_clicked() 
}

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "listecontact.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();

}

#include "node.h"

Node::Node(Contact &c): _c(c),_next(0)
{

}
```

// this is what you guys would consider the main()

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "listecontact.h"
#include "contact.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;

}
void MainWindow::on_pbAjouter_clicked()//the program almost work in this function apart from the fact that it always takes the same contact over and over again
{
    int type;

    if(ui->rbPreN->isChecked()) type=0;
    else if(ui->rbNomP->isChecked()) type=1;

    Contact contact;
    contact.setPrenom(ui->lnPrenom->text().replace(";","_"));//ignore this part
    contact.setNom(ui->lnNom->text().replace(";","_"));
    contact.setTel(ui->lnTel->text().replace(";","_"));
    contact.setEmail(ui->lnEmail->text().replace(";","_"));
    liste.lLContactAdd(contact);//Here, i add the contact to my linked list

    ui->listWidget->clear();
    if(type){
        for(int i = 0; i < liste.getSize();i++)   //I display the contact on my interface
        {


        ui->listWidget->addItem(liste.get(i).nom()+liste.get(i).prenom());

            //ui->listWidget->addItem(contact.nom())+(",")+(contact.prenom());  // i can add as many contact as i want but it will always be the same one (the last one i added)
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < liste.getSize();i++)
        {

            ui->listWidget->addItem(liste.get(i).prenom()+liste.get(i).nom());
        }

    }

} 
void MainWindow::on_rbPreN_clicked()  // the program crashes here this is where i sort the list 
{

int a = liste.getSize();
        ui->listWidget->clear();
        //tribulle(1);

        for(int i = 0; i < liste.getSize();i++)
        {

            ui->listWidget->addItem(liste.get(i).prenom()+(",")+liste.get(i).nom()); // it gives me a segmentation fault when i try to return my current pointer 
        }
}
```

Comment: TLDR : the way i use/declare my object is probably wrong, you should focus on the object "liste" from ListeContact and the fonction get(index) (pass through the linked list  "index" amount and return a contact. Also, i cannot create different contact with LLContactAdd, it takes the last contact i typed and makes multiple copies which might be part of the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is due to a small character `'&'` added in the `class Node` !!!

**Problem** - Using a local variable `Contact contact;` and transmit it by value then by reference up to `class Node`.

> In the `MainWindow::on_pbAjouter_clicked()`, when you are adding a
>   contact by `liste.lLContactAdd(contact);`, it is by value (`void
>   lLContactAdd(Contact c);`).
>
> Then from `ListeContact` to `Node` it is transmit by reference
>   `Node(Contact &c)` using data on stack to be stored in `Node`
>   (`Contact &_c;`).

Even when creating a new `Contact` in the main function, the result will be stored from a stack value.

**Solution** - just force the `Node` to create a `Contact` by removing the `&`.

> The local `Contact c` created in the `ListeContact` will be stored in
>   a new `Contact _c;` of the `Node`.

```
class Node
{
public:
    // Contact &_c; // to be replaced
    Contact _c;
    Node(Contact &c);
    Node * _next;
};
```

Comment: wow, ur MY SAVIOR!!!! IT WORKS. Thank you so much!